# How to approach finding lines that are perpendicular to each other with as little calculations as possible?

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Say we are given equation of a line in $ \mathbb{R^2}$ : $$k:2x+4y-1=0$$Now we want to find a line that is perpendicular to the line $k$ with as little calculations and transformations as possible, so that we can find it relatively quickly,

How one would go about doing that? - I'd suggest using vectors, but I, myself have trouble with expressing these relations simply...

Comment: Can we not rearrange it into the form $y=mx+c$ and use the fact that the gradients of perpendicular lines multiply together to give -1?

Comment: We can forget about the 1 (because of parallellism), and then all $x$ and $y$ that satisfy this equation are exactly those that are perpendicular to the vector (2,4). Hence, the lines $y-2x+k=0, k \in \mathbb{R}$ are all those that are perpendicular

Comment: @LukasRollier Yes, that's true, but what about using properties of vectors, possibly the dot product and vector multiplication? - would that be manageable to do quickly?

Comment: I am using the dot product. Having the condition $2x+4y=0$ is the same as the condition $(2,4) \cdot (x,y)$=0

Comment: And hence, $(2,4)$ is perpendicular to $(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the vector of the line $k$ is $n=(2,-1)$. Assume that the perpendicular line passes the point $(x_1,y_1)$, then, in vector form, its equation is given by

$$(x-x_1,y-y_1)\cdot n=0$$

Comment: Haven't really seen the equation of a line in the vector form like this before, if we were to express it in the same form as the line $k$ what would we get?
Because as I understand we have two cases when lines are either parallel or perpendicular, and these come from the vector properties of dot product?

Comment: @UndergraduateWannabe - If you carry out the dot product, you get the equation $2(x-x_1)+4(y-y_1)=0$.

Comment: That's correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your question is limited to $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can

1. find the slope $m$
2. take all lines with slope $-1/m$ of the form $y=b -x/m$ for any $b$.

Comment: Sure, but could we use properties of two vectors that are perpendicular and use vector multiplication/ dot product to find this line?